# optim in R, finding numeric solution

Tags: r

I need to find exact and numerical solutions to a function but my code in R shows Error in optim(start_val[i, ], g) :
function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

that is my code:

```
g <- function(x) (3*x[1]+2*x[2]+4*x[3]-4)^2 + (4*x[1]+2*x[2]+4*x[3]-2)^2 + (1*x[1]+1*x[2]+4*x[3]-4)^2

start_val <- expand.grid(c(-10,0,10),c(-10,0,10),c(-10,0,10))

optim_on_a_multiple_grid <- function(start_val, fun, ...) {
    
    opt_result <- sapply(1:nrow(start_val),                 
                         function(i) {                           
                           res <- optim(start_val[i,], g)                           
                           c(res[[1]], res[[2]], res[[4]])                            
                         })
    
    rownames(opt_result) <-
      c(paste("x_", 1:ncol(start_val),           
              "_start_val", sep = ""),          
        paste("x_", 1:ncol(start_val),               
              "_sol", sep = ""),           
        paste(c(deparse(substitute(          
          fun          
        )), "_min"), collapse = ""),       
        "convergence")
    
    opt_result    
  }

round(optim_on_a_multiple_grid(expand.grid(c(-10, 0, 10), c(-10, 0, 10)), g), 3)
```

Please, point me at my mistakes and explain how to fix them, I am stuck on it for quite a while now

Comment: Why would you use optim? You are not trying to do optimization. Simply have `g(c(1,2,3))` and that will give you exact solution

Comment: @onyambu I am trying to use optim because it was requested to be included by the professor

Comment: So what is your goal? to find the minimum of the function?

Comment: @onyambu I need to minimize the function using optim and give the numeric solution. A similar code works for 2 variables and looks like this:
g <- function(x) (x[1]*x[2]-6)^2 + (x[ 1] + x[2] - 5)^2
start_val <- expand.grid(c(0,2.5,5),c(0,2.5,5))
optim_on_a_multiple_grid <- function(start_val, fun, ...){
  opt_result <- sapply(1:nrow(start_val),
                       function(i) {
                         res <- optim(start_val[i,],fun,...)
                         c(res[[1]],res[[2]],res[[4]])
                       }
  )
  
  opt_result <- rbind(t(start_val),opt_result)

Comment: @onyambu
and continues here:

  rownames(opt_result) <- 
    c(paste("x_", 1:ncol(start_val),
            "_start_val", sep=""),
      paste("x_", 1:ncol(start_val),
            "_sol", sep=""),
      paste(c(deparse(substitute(
        
        fun )), "_min"), collapse=""), "convergence")
  
  opt_result
  
}

round(optim_on_a_multiple_grid(expand.grid(c(0,2.5,5), c(0,2.5,5)),g),3)

optim(par=c(0, 2.5), fn=g)

Comment: @onyambu
I need to do now the same thing but modify it for 3 variables but I am confused what exactly I need to change

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why you have alot of objects while your aim is to optimize:

Do

```
# Define g
g <- function(x){
  a <- (3 * x[1] + 2 * x[2] + 4 * x[3] - 4)^2
  b <- (4 * x[1] + 2 * x[2] + 4*x[3] - 2)^2
  d <- (x[1] + x[2] + 4*x[3] - 4)^2
  a +b +d
}


optim(par=c(0,0,1), fn=g)
$par
[1] -1.9998762  3.9996836  0.5000453

$value
[1] 8.468819e-09

$counts
function gradient 
     160       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

If you need your code:

The problem lies at the very end of it:

You should have:

```
 round(optim_on_a_multiple_grid(start_val, g), 3)
```

---

### Edit

Exact Solution:

```
A <- matrix(c(3, 2, 4,
              4, 2, 4, 
              1, 1, 4), 3, byrow = TRUE)
b <- c(4, 2, 4)

solve(A, b)
[1] -2.0  4.0  0.5
```

Check the results against those produced by the `optim` function

Comment: Typo: twice `x[2]` in computing `b`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are talking about but I need to stick to the format I mentioned above and correct something there

Comment: @user778 check edit

Comment: @onyambu Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Comment: @user778 you frogot to include `opt_result <- rbind(t(start_val),opt_result)` in your `optim_on_a_multiple_grid` function. The problem is you copied the code incorrectly.